# Dart how to acces directly to a Map awaited data

Tags: dart

I have a function that return a `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>` and I would like to return one of the map values instead of the whole map. For the moment I have to do it like this:

```dart
  static Future<bool> fileClearCompleted() async {
    var res = await rsApiCall('/rsFiles/FileDownloads');
    return res['retval'];
  }
```

`rsApiCall` return a valid JSON object. So what I would like to find is a more elegant way to return the parameter `res['retval']` like:

```dart
  static Future<bool> fileClearCompleted() async => await rsApiCall('/rsFiles/FileDownloads')['retval'];
```

But this don't work, neither with cascade operator like: `await rsApiCall('/rsFiles/FileDownloads')..['retval'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be (see the added parenthesis):

```
  static Future<bool> fileClearCompleted() async =>
      (await rsApiCall('/rsFiles/FileDownloads'))['retval'];
```

Since we want to `await` the `rsApiCall` and then use the `[]` operator on that result.

Comment: That works properly, also when when you want to access to methods: `(await data).map((e) => e.mMsgId).cast<String>().toList();`